# how do I overcome nesting in functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm pretty new to javascript and jquery, and have run into a problem that I have not yet found a solution for.  I'll attempt to paint it in a fairly simple way.

I have a page that offers the user a few choices (its a game, so..) like attack or defend, what weapon to use.  It then loads two html 's, each with a "commit" button.  The commit buttons are tied to (separate) functions that pass data to ajax.

The problem I have is that I'm getting buried in nested functions.  Does that make sense?  My code looks something like this:

code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#choice1').click(function() {
        //do some stuff
  });
  $('#choice2').click(function() {
         //do some stuff
   });
  $('#choice3').click(function() {
        //do some stuff, including creating the choices below, and their submit boxes
        $('#subChoice1').click(function() {
              //send data with ajax to a php document.  get result
              //create some text on my document to display results
              //create an input button, along with an id="subButton1"
        });
        $('#subChoice2').click(function() {
              //send data with ajax to a php document.  get result
              //create some text on my document to display results
              //create an input button, along with id="subButton1"
              //(yes, feed both back to same func)
        });
  });  // end choice3
  $('#subButton1').click(function() {
              //my buttons in the subChoices do not call this function(!!??)
  });
});
```

*edit: link no longer works, sorry.* And I've created a [living example here.](http://dixieandtheninjas.net/hunter/dev/hunter_test.php)

Thanks for any tips or pointers.  I'm almost certain that there is just something simple that I'm missing or unaware of that will get me on the right track.

Comment: why do you have your click bind nested?

Comment: because I don't know a better way to do it.  I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use normal named functions instead of inline anonymous ones.  That might help if the mountain of functions is getting too tall.

**Update:**

Here's your working Case 1:

```
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Alright. Button 1 worked.  Here\'s another button.</br></span>');
        $('#div1').append('<input type="button" value = "Button 2" id="button2"/>')

        $('#button2').click(function() {
            $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Hey!  Button 2 worked!.  Let\'s keep going.</br></span>');
            $('#div1').append('<input type="button" value = "Button 3" id="button3"/>')

                $('#button3').click(function() {
                    $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Hey!  Button 3 worked!.  That\'s probably enough.</br></span>');

                });
        });

    });
```

What I'm proposing is to update it like this:

```
    function button3_click() {
        $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Hey!  Button 3 worked!.  That\'s probably enough.</br></span>');
    }

    function button2_click() {
         $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Hey!  Button 2 worked!.  Let\'s keep going.</br></span>');
         $('#div1').append('<input type="button" value = "Button 3" id="button3"/>');
         $('#button3').click(button3_click);
    }

    function button1_click() {
        $('#div1').append('<span id="span1"><br>Alright. Button 1 worked.  Here\'s another button.</br></span>');
        $('#div1').append('<input type="button" value = "Button 2" id="button2"/>')
        $('#button2').click(button2_click);
    }

    $('#button1').click(button1_click);
```

That way the structure of the logic stays the same, but you can pull out the nested function definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That seems like the right way to go, but I'm not sure how to execute it in jquery.  Check out the code here:   http://www.dixieandtheninjas.net/hunter/dev/test.js   (case 1 has inline anonymous functions, which work just fine.  Case 2 is similar, but the functions are not inline, and thus the buttons that are created are unable to reference the functions)

Comment: @Jeremy: Those functions are still inline.  See my example for what I meant by named functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're consistently reusing classes or ids for the submit buttons you can leverage jQuery's `live()` method.  It would allow you to create the bindings for `$('#subChoice1')` and `$('#subChoice2')` outside of the click handler for the parent choice, but still have them bind up properly when they're created.